# Apache POI - Excel Import, insert data from a new sheet into a column

Tags: java, excel, apache

I'm here to ask for help in my java project in Netbeans.

I'm using Apache POI to import/export excel data. To make you understand what is the problem in my application, I'm showing you a print of the debug.

[image: print1]

In the print, you can see 2 sheets. The first header "aiai" and the data from that sheet.

My problem is: How do i insert the data from "aiai2" which is the second sheet from my excel file, in its proper place, below the header "aiai2"

On other words, I want to separate the sheets vertically.

Below, I will show my code:

```
Workbook wb;

public String Importar(File archivo, JTable tablaD) {
    String answer = "Unable to import";
    DefaultTableModel modeloT = new DefaultTableModel();
    tablaD.setModel(modeloT);
    tablaD.getModel();
    tablaD.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    try {
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivo));
        int nsheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();

        for (int i = 0; i < nsheets; i++) {

            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
            Iterator filaIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

            int rownum = -1;
            while (filaIterator.hasNext()) {
                rownum++;
                Row fila = (Row) filaIterator.next();
                /*if (i > 0) {//se o nr da ficha atual for maior que 0, começa a escrever as linhas apartir da row 0 da tabela
                    modeloT.moveRow(modeloT.getRowCount() -1, modeloT.getRowCount() - 1, 0);
                }*/
                Iterator columnaIterator = fila.cellIterator();
                Object[] listaColumna = new Object[1000];
                int columnnum = -1;
                while (columnaIterator.hasNext()) {
                    columnnum++;
                    Cell celda = (Cell) columnaIterator.next();

                    if (rownum == 0) {
                        modeloT.addColumn(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        if (celda != null) {
                            switch (celda.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    listaColumna[columnnum] = (int) Math.round(celda.getNumericCellValue());
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    listaColumna[columnnum] = celda.getStringCellValue();
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    listaColumna[columnnum] = celda.getBooleanCellValue();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    listaColumna[columnnum] = celda.getDateCellValue();
                                    break;
                            }//end switch case
                            System.out.println("Column:" + columnnum + " Row:" + rownum + " value:" + celda + ".");

                        }
                    }
                }//end while column Iterator
                if (rownum != 0) {
                    modeloT.addRow(listaColumna);
                }
            }//end while row iterator
        }//end for
        answer = "Imported with success";

    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return answer;
}

public String Exportar(File archivo, JTable tablaD) {
    String answer = "Unable to export";
    int numFila = tablaD.getRowCount(), numColumna = tablaD.getColumnCount();
    if (archivo.getName().endsWith("xls")) {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    } else {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }
    Sheet hoja = wb.createSheet("Default");

    try {
        for (int i = -1; i < numFila; i++) {
            Row fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < numColumna; j++) {
                Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                if (i == -1) {
                    celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(tablaD.getColumnName(j)));
                } else {
                    celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(tablaD.getValueAt(i, j)));
                }
                wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo));
            }
        }
        answer = "Exported with success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, I assume you want to create a separate table for each sheet, one below other. In that case you need to create a new table everytime you read a new sheet. If you use only one table, you will get only one header.

Try this :

Create a new method `Importar` that takes a new table and a `Sheet` parameter

```
public String Importar(JTable tablaD, Sheet sheet) {
    String answer = "Unable to import";
    DefaultTableModel modeloT = new DefaultTableModel();
    tablaD.setModel(modeloT);
    tablaD.getModel();
    tablaD.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);


    try {


            Iterator filaIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

            int rownum = -1;
            ....
            ....
```

So the calling method would be :

```
try {
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivo));
    int nsheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();

    for (int i = 0; i < nsheets; i++) {
           //You have to make sure your JTable gets rendered.
           JTable tablaD = new JTable();
           Importar( tablaD, wb.getSheetAt(i) );
    }
} catch ( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Important point is that your new table needs to get rendered or added to frame each time before you call `Importar`

Comment: Well, I tried ur method and an error appeared in my controller: modeloE.Importar(archivo, vistaE.jtDatos), because i removed the JTable parameter, i had to remove as well that "vistaE.jtDatos" and the error disappeared, however, when i import the excel file, it doesn't show any data, its blank. But, in the console, the data is being added to the table.

Comment: It seems you are adding `JTable` to frame before calling `Importar`, do not disturb your existing method, just create a new method as suggested in my answer and try.